# Parsing incoming json with angular and put it into an array

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I have an incoming json like this:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Test",
            "st": "ok"
        },
        {
            "name": "Test2",
            "st": "ko"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to parse it into an angular interface and than convert it into an array.

I tryed with some different type of interfaces but i can't really have my final result.
Usually, I use this method for convert the response that i recive (after put it into a service and call it with `httpclient.get`, and an `Observable<Object>` as method return):

```
this.service.getTest().subscribe({
      next: (response) =>{
        
        console.log(response)
        let responseList = (response as Array<Interface>)
        responseList.foreach((u)=>{
           this.globVar.push({
                 ...
             })
            })

      },
      error: (msg) =>{
        console.log(msg)
      }
    })
```

Comment: `response` is not an array. Probably you should do: `let responseList = (response.results as Array<Interface>);` And this would simplify everything, no need to iterate with `.forEach()`